What are the rule of Native Tokens symbol (EIP-7809)?
Native Tokens (NTs) introduced in EIP-7809 have a token_id (i.e. a symbol) where ETH is the default native token ID.
What are the restrictions about this symbol? Where is the documentation about it?
Ultimately the question is how do you create a NT and is it possible to set the ID as eth (i e. ETH in lowercase)?

Hey, the EIP is still in the early stages, so the final design is TBD. I recommend asking this question on the Ethereum Magicians forum.

This question is not relevant as explained in @Paul's comment above -  NT is in still a recent EIP. Sorry for the noise. Still,I found the answer to my question in the current state of this proposal (e.g. Multiple Native Tokens).
The value of a token_id is equal to the Ethereum address of its associated smart contract. It is not a string. There won't be any risk of case-sensitive mistake/impersonation.
